# SearchResponse - from and size info in response

Tags: elasticsearch

I have started to play around with ES, and trying to figure out something with the responses and the data which was returned.

I have set up basic environment by following the tutorials on ES documentation, and was able to index some sample docs.

When I query ES with:

```
TransportClient client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(server.elasticHost, Integer.valueOf(server.elasticPort)));
  SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("testme").setTypes("tester").setQuery(elasticQuery).execute().actionGet();
```

I got some docs as response but cant find the "from" and "size" ("start" and "row" values in Solr, if you are familiar with it)in the JAVA API.

Am I supposed to use some other classes for search retrieval or add some more params while I am querying ES? I have also come up with  [Scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html), so is this the way that I can get from - size data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your request you haven't set the `from` or `size` parameters, so `from` defaults to 0 and `size` defaults to 10. If you want to change the defaults or use `from` and `size` for pagination do so in the request.

```
 SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("testme")
        .setTypes("tester")
        .setQuery(elasticQuery)
        .setFrom(21)
        .setSize(20)
        .execute().actionGet();
```

Comment: my question was about getting from and size values back, rather than setting them up with the request, sth like response.getFrom() which seems like not possible with the java api?

Comment: No it is not possible to get `from` and `size` from the response object. If you are not setting those values in the request the `from` is `0` and the `size` is `10`, if you are setting them in the request you have those values already.